# Allow users to issue multiple commands to Alexa after using the launch phrase once

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

If every intent requires the invocation name of the skill, then what is the purpose of the launch phrase?

For example, this would make sense:

```
"Alexa, open adventure game"  (launch phrase)
"move forward"                (intent)
"pick up item"                (intent)
"close adventure game"        (exit)
```

But from what I've seen you have to do this:

```
"Alexa, open adventure game"                (launch phrase)
"Alexa, ask adventure game to move forward" (intent)
"Alexa, ask adventure game to pick up item" (intent)
"Alexa, close adventure game"               (exit)
```

My real issue here is that the dialog structure of "Alexa, ask {invocation_name} to {utterance}" is too bloated, and it's hard to see from the documentation how to get around this. I'm hoping that I'm missing something in how the launch phrase works will that allow my users to issue commands more naturally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use the invocation name every time if you keep the session alive. In order to do that you have to include `shouldEndSession` parameter and set it to `false` in your response JSON. Alexa ends the session when  `shouldEndSession` is set to `true` or if its not present.

**Ex:** for `LaunchRequest` give  response like this.

```
{
   'version':'1.0',
   'sessionAttributes':{

   },
   'response':{
      'outputSpeech':{
         'type':'PlainText',
         'text':'Launch phrase here'
      },          
      'reprompt':{
         'outputSpeech':{
            'type':'PlainText',
            'text':'re-prompt phrase here'
         }
      },
      'shouldEndSession':false
   }
}
```

Note that `shouldEndSession` is false, and this keep the session alive. And the user can just say ***"move forward"*** without using the invocation name.

And when you actually want to end the session set `shouldEndSession` to `true`.

**Ex**: for `Amazon.StopIntent`

**Note:** Even if you set `shouldEndSession` to `false` , the default Alexa session timeout is 8 seconds and it is not configurable.

Answer (score 0):

Every intent *does not* require the invocation name.

The following is very much possible:

```
"Alexa, open adventure game"  (launch phrase)
"move forward"                (intent)
"pick up item"                (intent)
"close adventure game"        (exit)
```

Have you had a problem with a skill, or is it just something you noticed while reading the sample utterances in the skills store?

If you are having a problem with a skill, it may be that the session is timing out, and the developer has provided no reprompt. In this case, the wake word + invocation (Alexa, open adventure game) has to be said to launch the skill again.

If you are just going by the examples you've given (the second set), you have to understand that each utterance is not just an intent utterance, it is a launch+intent utterance. What that means is, each of these examples are meant for launching a skill *and* an intent. So basically your example is

```
"Alexa, open adventure game"                (launch phrase)
"Alexa, ask adventure game to move forward" (launch phrase + intent)
"Alexa, ask adventure game to pick up item" (launch phrase + intent)
"Alexa, close adventure game"               (launch phrase + exit)
```

These utterances are not meant to be said one after the other, they are all standalone commands.

Once a skill has been launched, you don't need to repeat the invocation again and again as long as the session is active.